# Angular form display one error message at a time

Tags: angular, validation, angular-forms

I am using Angular 6 and I have a form and inside that I have two fields Name and Display name. I have 3-4 validation on both the fields like required, pattern, min length, max length. I want to display only single error message at a time. How to achieve that?

Here is the sample code.

```
<mat-form-field required>
            <label for="attribute_name">Name</label>
            <input type="text"
                   required
                   matInput
                   [(ngModel)]="attribute.name"
                   name="name"
                   id="attribute_name"
                   #nameInput="ngModel"
                   [ngClass]="{'form-validation--error-border' : (nameInput?.errors && (nameInput?.dirty || nameInput?.touched)) || false}"
                   [minlength]="3"
                   [maxlength]="63"
                   [pattern]="[some pattern]" />
            <ul *ngIf="nameInput.errors && (nameInput.dirty || nameInput.touched)" class="form-validation form-validation--error">
                <li *ngIf="nameInput.errors.required">Name is required</li>
                <li *ngIf="nameInput.errors.minlength">Minimum length should be 3.</li>
                <li *ngIf="nameInput.errors.pattern">It should start with letter.</li>
            </ul>
        </mat-form-field>
```

Comment: I would use ngx-valdemort: https://ngx-valdemort.ninja-squad.com. Disclaimer: I am the author.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try ngTemplate *ngIf, else

```
<ul *ngIf="nameInput.errors && (nameInput.dirty || nameInput.touched)" class="form-validation form-validation--error">
   <li *ngIf="nameInput.errors.required; else minLengthElem;">Name is required</li>
</ul>
   <ngTemplate #minLengthElem>   
    <li *ngIf="nameInput.errors.minlength; else patternElem;">Minimum length should be 3.</li>
  </ngTemplate>
  <ngTemplate #patternElem>
    <li *ngIf="nameInput.errors.pattern">It should start with letter.</li>
  </ngTemplate>
```

Comment: I used this approach. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

Template:

```
<ul *ngIf="nameInput.errors && (nameInput.dirty || nameInput.touched)" class="form-validation form-validation--error">
  <li [innerHtml]="getErrorMessage(nameInput.errors)"></li>
</ul>
```

TS:

```
 getErrorMessage(errors: any) {
    if (errors.required) {
      return "Name is required"
    } else if (errors.minlength) {
      return "Minimum length should be 3"
    } else if (errors.pattern) {
      return "It should start with letter"
    }
  }
```

Comment: is it a good way to call the method directly from the template side? it will always call again and again to check for an update which eventually leads to performance issue I guess.

Comment: Evaluating something from template or TS is same, no performance issue, even if you write the same thing in template, the save logic gets computed, writing in it TS is just making it simpler

Comment: Why `*ngIf="required"`? Why use innerHTML instead of simple and safe interpolation?

Comment: @JBNizet `*ngIf="required"` was a mistake.

Comment: @AdritaSharma Nope there is the difference I guess, try to add simple method in property binding in the template with some console in it and do the same thing on button click you will see the difference.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of checking error using

```
nameInput.errors.minlength
```

You should use `hasError` like this -

```
nameInput.hasError('min')
```

Comment: it's having error that's why it's displaying 3 error messages but I want to display only one error message which has higher priority.